# How to use sort_by, by proximity to a number in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to write a method that will sort an array of numbers, by proximity to ten:

```
def test_sort_by_proximity_to_ten                                         
  prices = [3.02, 9.91, 17.9, 10.01, 11.0]
  sorted = prices.sort_by do |p|                                        
    # Not sure how to sort by proximity here
  end                             
  assert_equal [10.01, 9.91, 11.0, 3.02, 17.9], sorted
end
```

I was thinking that perhaps I could use some sort of range, but was falling way short on my attempts.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
prices.sort_by { |price| (10 - price).abs }
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me achieve what I was seeking to do.